# Как найти нужный кортеж в списке python?

Tags: python, list, tuple

У меня есть кортежи в списке:

```
[
    (1, 'test1@gmail.com', 'mark'), 
    (2, 'test2@gmail.com', 'alisa'), 
    (3, 'test3@gmail.com', 'elon')
]
```

Как найти индекс кортежа, в котором имя будет '**`alisa`**'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [
    (1, 'test1@gmail.com', 'mark'), 
    (2, 'test2@gmail.com', 'alisa'), 
    (3, 'test3@gmail.com', 'elon')
]

idx = [*map(lambda x: x[2], a)].index('alisa') # либо list(map(...))...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = [
    (1, 'test1@gmail.com', 'mark'), 
    (2, 'test2@gmail.com', 'alisa'), 
    (3, 'test3@gmail.com', 'elon')
]

res = next(x[0] for x in lst if x[2]=="alisa")
```